# Data Load into Accounts (Std Obj) with a Lookup to Custom Object

Tags: lookup, data-loader, account, import, field-mapping

The issue is that I am not able to map the LookUp Field with a value from the CSV as the Lookup Field is not displayed for Mapping. Tried Import Wizard, Data Loader, Workbench, Jitterbit ... None of them display the Lookup Field for Mapping? Is there an issue that Salesforce does not expose the Custom Lookup Field in Account Object to be mapped?

I tried both Insert and Upsert options and the Custom Object has an External Id Field defined as well...

Comment: Is the field marked as deployed?

Comment: Is the filed visible and editable by the profile that you are using?

Comment: Ha it just turned out to be the Profile Level permission ... thought I used Sys Admin profile this particular Field was not accessible ... thanks for the comments ...